# Breadth-First Search takes way too long to solve maze

Tags: java, breadth-first-search, path-finding, maze

I have an big, open maze like this:

```
############################################################
#.....................#...#................#.........#.....#
#..##.......x.........#.#.#...#.........x..#......#..#.....#
#...#.......#....#....#.#.#...#...####.....####...#..#####.#
#.....###...#....#....###.#...#.........#.........#......#.#
####.#..#...#....#........#...#####..#..#...#######..##..#.#
#....##.....#....#................#..####......#...........#
#......##...######........x....................#......######
#....##........................................#...........#
#.........##########...############........#...#...####....#
#.....#...#..#..#..#......#.......#........#...#....###....#
#######...#..#..#..#......#.......#.....####...............#
#.....#...#..#..#..#......#.......#........................#
#.....#####..#..#..#......#.......######............x......#
#.........................#................................#
#..................x......#..##..........#####.............#
#.........................####.............................#
#..........................................................#
#....##.....#....#................#..####......#...........#
#.....s##...######.............................#......######
#....##........................................#...........#
#.........##########...############........#...#...####....#
#.....#...#..#..#..#......#.......#........#...#....###....#
#######...#..#..#..#......#.......#...x.####...............#
#.....#...#..#...x.#......#.......#.................#......#
#.....#####..#..#..#...#..###....#######............######.#
#...............#..x...#..#.....##...........####...#......#
#...............#......#.........#.........##...#..........#
#...............#......#.........#..........#............#.#
############################################################
```

"s" is the starting point. And there are multiple destination points "x". I just need to find one destination. The BFS algorithm can find a solution pretty quick if a destination is close to the starting point. If they are further away like in the example above, it takes endless time.
So my questions are:
a) Is the algorithm bad for this specific type of maze and should I rather use A* or something like that.
b) Is my implementation bad?

Implementation:

```
public class BFS {

    public static String getPath(String[][] map) {
        String[] ways = { "L", "R", "U", "D" }; // directions to go
        Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<>();
        q.offer("");
        String path = "";

        while (!foundBait(map, path)) {
            path = q.poll();

            for (String s : ways) {
                String newPath = path + s;
                if (valid(map, newPath))
                    q.offer(newPath);
            }
        }
        return path;
    }

    private static boolean foundBait(String[][] map, String moves) {
        int xStart = 0;
        int yStart = 0;

        for (int y = 0; y < map.length; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < map[0].length; x++)
                if (map[y][x].equals("s")) {
                    xStart = x;
                    yStart = y;
                }

        int i = xStart;
        int j = yStart;

        for (int s = 0; s < moves.length(); s++) {

            if (moves.charAt(s) == "L".charAt(0))
                i--;
            else if (moves.charAt(s) == "R".charAt(0))
                i++;
            else if (moves.charAt(s) == "U".charAt(0))
                j--;
            else if (moves.charAt(s) == "D".charAt(0))
                j++;

        }

        if (map[j][i].equals("x"))
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    private static boolean valid(String[][] map, String moves) {
        int xStart = 0;
        int yStart = 0;

        for (int y = 0; y < map.length; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < map[0].length; x++)
                if (map[y][x].equals("s")) {
                    xStart = x;
                    yStart = y;
                }

        int i = xStart;
        int j = yStart;

        for (int s = 0; s < moves.length(); s++) {

            if (moves.charAt(s) == "L".charAt(0))
                i--;
            else if (moves.charAt(s) == "R".charAt(0))
                i++;
            else if (moves.charAt(s) == "U".charAt(0))
                j--;
            else if (moves.charAt(s) == "D".charAt(0))
                j++;

            if (!(0 <= i && i < map[0].length && 0 <= j && j < map.length))
                return false;
            else if (map[j][i].equals("#") || map[j][i].equals("-"))
                return false;

        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? It seems to me that you've made a mistake in your algorithm implementation somewhere. It shouldn't take too long, your map is only like 30x30, it isn't that much for modern computers.

Comment: BFS is not appropriate for such a problem because it is a traversing algorithm. If you want to find the shortest path between 2 points you could use Dijkstra's algorithm for example.

Comment: It's been years since I delved into A* or Dijkstra but if memory serves those really are effective where the cost to traverse along the graph space varies. In other words, it can find a 'shortest path' among many paths but I don't think your criteria is such. If you're just looking for "any" path to "any" x I think BFS is the way to do it.

Comment: @Vladimir he doesn't want to find the shortest path. He wants to find 'any' path to any x. Different problem. Dijkstra is essentially a BFS when all the costs to move 1 grid space is the same.

Comment: No, it is not, because BFS it's made  originally for trees where you have no loops. And from what i see from his code he doesn't mark in anyway the partial paths, thus entering an infinite loop from which most probably he gets endless processing time. But yes, you can adapt it for graphs, if you mark the visited nodes.

Comment: @Vladimir do you know some resources where I can check about bfs marking visiting nodes? I considered dijkstra as well but as spartygw said dijkstra is the same as bfs when the costs are always 1. Nevertheless y'all were helpful already.

Comment: You have an example here : https://www.baeldung.com/java-breadth-first-search. In your case, you could either create a second matrix in which you mark visited positions, or a set of integers, where each integer is the flattened position in your matrix. For example map[1][1] would be set[1*n +1], where n is your matrix number of columns. So map[i][j] -> set[i*n + j]

Comment: @Vladimir Thanks man I just tried with the 2nd matrix marking the positions. It works perfectly and way faster than before. :)

Comment: Glad i could help

Comment: I will also add the comment as an answer so you can mark as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, problem was not marking the nodes added to the paths, and the solution is to use a second matrix for marking.